# LWC: Read entries from custom Object without creating Apex Class

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, list, custom, object

how can I create a list of entries from a custom object in Salesforce without needing to create an Apex Class with this list?

using only the JS and the HTML files from the lightning web component?

```
JS
import the necessary stuff
export the list...

HTML
<ul>
<li>repeat this item with SF custom object entries</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean `query` records itself without using Apex?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's currently nothing in the LWC framework allowing to query multiple records at once. You will need Apex to to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, currently, a way to do this without writing custom Apex *other than using a feature that is in beta*. So, full disclosure, anything in beta may not necessarily see a full release so use your judgement before deciding to use a beta feature. The reason why this functionality wasn't baked into the Lightning Data Service from the beginning is likely, how do you determine what subset of records you want to see in your component and how should they be ordered? Telling Salesforce what you want to see and how you want to see it organized is almost always a query operation.

All that being said, there is a [beta feature in the UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_list_ui) called `getListUi` that uses an existing List View for an object to tell the UI API what records you want to see.

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getListUi, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, listViewApiName: 'AllAccounts' })
    propertyOrFunction;
}
```